# Preview cannot display two different eps files with the same name simultaneously

Tags: pdf, preview, postscript

I am running OS X 10.9.5 on a 2010 Macbook Pro.  I have two eps files that I want to use Preview to view (Preview really converts the eps files to pdfs).  One file is ~/Research/images/test.eps and the other file is ~/Desktop/test.eps.  The first file displays sin(x), the second displays cos(x).

If I open the first file, it shows the correct plot (i.e. sin(x)).  Now if I open the second file (keeping the first open), the second plot correctly displays cos(x). However, the first instance of test.pdf automatically changes from sin(x) to cos(x). When I was using OS X 10.6.8, this never happened.

This makes it very difficult to compare plots (with the same name).  Is there a setting I can change or a way around this?

Comment: Yes. I would have the first window was originally viewing sin(x) and the second window opens and displays cos(x).  The first window then automatically changes to displaying cos(x).

Comment: So you want to Open two instances of Preview at once.

Comment: That is correct. To view two different eps files with the same name at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use and [Open two instances of Preview at once](http://www.macworld.com/article/1158007/opentwoinstancesofoneapp.html).

> Unfortunately, Preview (like most Mac OS X applications) lets you have
>   just one instance of a file open at a time. But there’s a way around
>   that restriction.
>
> The open command line program accepts a parameter -n that allows it to
>   launch the application again, even if it’s already running. So, if
>   you’re currently viewing file.pdf in Preview, enter open -n file.pdf
>   in Terminal. (You’ll need to supply the full and complete path to the
>   file, of course; the easiest way to do that is to type in open -n,
>   then drag the file from the Finder to the Terminal command line.)
>   Another instance of Preview will launch, complete with its own Dock
>   icon, with the PDF document open.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. It is kind of annoying to have to do this, when this wasn't an issue in Snow Leopard.

Comment: maybe there is another way, but glad to hear this worked for you.